# Is Python's secrets module random enough for a raffle?

Tags: randomness

Would `secrets.choice` be random enough to pick winners in a raffle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. According to the Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html)

> The secrets module is used for generating cryptographically strong
> random numbers suitable for managing data such as passwords, account
> authentication, security tokens, and related secrets.

In the background, `secrets` doesn't use a PRNG like `random`. In Linux specifically it uses `\dev\urandom` which is considered cryptographically secure and is used by popular cryptographic libraries like OpenSSL. In Windows, it uses `RtlGenRandom`.

Comment: Thank you! So if I have a list of names `['John Smith', 'Jane Doe', 'Jane Doe', 'Joe Public']` (Jane Doe bought two tickets), and call `secrets.choice(names)` it will be as secure as drawing a random paper ticket?

Comment: `random` actually supports multiple generators including `SystemRandom` which uses the same urandom-or-equivalent source as `secrets` does. `secrets` was added later as a module that would be harder to accidentally misuse if you need cryptographic randomness. @Someone, it's secure if you trust the computer you run it on. A paper drawing may (or may not) be more difficult to hack.

Comment: @benrg Thanks, I didn't know that, I will update my answer accordingly